# Vue component does not render html under hidden dropdown-menu

Tags: laravel, vue.js

`<div class="dropdown notification-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class=" nav-link" title="search"><img src="{{ asset('front/img/notification-bell-ico.svg') }}" alt=""> </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="card notification-card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <p>Notification</p>
                    <a href="notification.html">See all</a>
                </div>
                <notification :user="{{ auth()->user() }}"></notification>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>`

I am loading my vue component as notification as seed in above code but some how it does not render html when i click header bell icon to open it 
I don't know how to resolve it

if any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please remove your extra close </a> `tag` as this appears to be bad formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet looks like a blade template and notification bells are often in a site's header area. It's possible your header is not within the root element you've got Vue controlling.